# How can i do the following in SAS?

Tags: sas

id  bill    product
1   1   A
1   1   B
1   2   C

For the above: 
For a ID if Bill number is same then create another column and put product separated by '-' and it for the same id the bill change then append the product with a different delimiter /

Comment: This question does not conform to StackOverflow rules. Please format your data, post the code you've tried and sample output would be good as well.

Answer (score 1):

Lets see if I can make sense of you question. (No offence meant)

For a ID if Bill number is same then 
create another column and put product separated by '-' 
and it for the same id the bill change then append the product with a different delimiter /

I understnad this as: 
If ID == Bill then  Nev_var= new_var + '-' + Product
else if ID != Bill then Nev_var = new_var + '/' + product

A way to to do this via using CATX:

```
data begin;
    length Id bill product $3; 
    input Id bill product;
    datalines;
    1 1 A 
    1 1 B 
    1 2 C
    2 2 D
    2 3 E
; 
run;



data wanted;
    format collect $1000.;
    retain collect;

    set begin; 
    if id = bill then collect = catx("-",collect,product);
    if id ~= bill then collect = catx("/",collect,product);
run;
```

Edit: user3142958 pointed out that the logic would be the other way around. Here is a fix.

```
data wanted;
    format collect $1000.;
    retain collect;
    set begin; 
    if id = bill then collect = catx("/",collect,product);
    if id ~= bill then collect = catx("-",collect,product);
run;
```

Comment: No the question is if for a ID bill number is same then use / as separator if not then use - .

Comment: +1 This answer has more than enough to help reach the OP goal, and *way* more than one could have hoped for given the quality/structure of the question.